# How can I use html video onerror event in Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, html5-video

I am building a video player with **Ionic**, I want to be able to play a video, but if that video is not available, it should play something else. I used **HTML5** `onerror` event but it's not working.

Here is the code:

```html
<video onerror="this.src=this.src=video.vid_default" [src]="video.vid_path"></video>
```

If the `video.vid_path` is not found, then the `video.vid_default` should be played by default.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using event binding, and putting the logic in a method? `<video (onerror)="changeVideoSrc()"...`

Comment: @WillAlexander how will `changeVideoSrc()` method look like

Comment: It will do whatever you need it to do, whatever is supposed to happen when the event is emitted...

Comment: @WillAlexander I want to change the source of the video to another video source

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a typo in `onerror="this.src=this.src=video.vid_default"` `this.src` is written twice.

Secondly, you need to bind the `onerror` event with an expression. This expression can be a statement or a method call.

```
<video (onerror)="this.src=video.vid_default" [src]="video.vid_path"></video>
```

Or

```
<video (onerror)="changeDefaultUrl($event,video.vid_default)" [src]="video.vid_path"></video>


changeDefaultUrl(event,url)
{
  this.src = url;
  event.target.src= url; //Set the url of the video tag
}
```